# Extract characters from a column and create new variable

Tags: regex, string, r

I have a column with character strings which I want to extract and create a new  column. I want to extract o3,no2,nox, pm10, pm25 and coarse from the first column. Additionally I want to extract the second last digit from the same column. What I want to have is shown under column lag and polut in the sample data

```
structure(list(pollutant = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
5L), .Label = c("Lag(coarse10, 6)", "Lag(no210, 0)", "Lag(nox10, 0)", 
"Lag(o3T10, 0)", "Lag(pm1010, 1)", "Lag(pm2510, 4)"), class = "factor"), 
    Estimate = c(0.0043156, -0.0049645, -0.0010619, -0.0070243, 
    -0.009382, -0.0017919, -0.0070243), lag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    4L, 6L, 1L), pollut = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    5L), .Label = c("coarse", "no2", "nox", "o3", "pm10", "pm25"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("pollutant", "Estimate", 
"lag", "pollut"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I just realized with code b<-str_sub(df$pollutant,-2,-2) from stringr package I could get the second last digit.

Comment: Do you want `o3T` instead of `o3` for the first row?

Comment: What is the rule? Why do you want to remove the `T` of `o3T`?

Comment: I modified my answer. Now, the `T` is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions (`dat` is the name of your data frame):

```
transform(dat, lag = gsub(".* (.)\\)", "\\1", pollutant),
               pollut = gsub(".*\\(([a-z0-9]+).*10\\,.*", "\\1", pollutant))

#          pollutant   Estimate lag pollut
# 1    Lag(o3T10, 0)  0.0043156   0     o3
# 2    Lag(no210, 0) -0.0049645   0    no2
# 3    Lag(nox10, 0) -0.0010619   0    nox
# 4   Lag(pm1010, 1) -0.0070243   1   pm10
# 5   Lag(pm2510, 4) -0.0093820   4   pm25
# 6 Lag(coarse10, 6) -0.0017919   6 coarse
# 7   Lag(pm1010, 1) -0.0070243   1   pm10
```