# Combine characters from two columns and create a new column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this.

```
name                zip   
Mike Tyson          13756
Mohammed Ali        54412
Joe Frazier         47463
Floyd Mayweahter    34134
```

I would like to use the first character of both the first name and last name, and the last two characters of the zip code to create a new variable

```
name                zip    new.var
Mike Tyson          13756  MT56
Mohammed Ali        54412  MA12
Joe Frazier         47463  JF63
Floyd Mayweahter    34134  FM34
```

I searched for a similar question, but here they use only one column [Extract characters from a column and create new variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051862/extract-characters-from-a-column-and-create-new-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R way with regex -

```
transform(df, new.var = paste0(sub('^(.)\\w+\\s(.).*', '\\1\\2', name), 
                               sub('.*(..)$', '\\1', zip)))

#              name   zip new.var
#1       Mike Tyson 13756    MT56
#2     Mohammed Ali 54412    MA12
#3      Joe Frazier 47463    JF63
#4 Floyd Mayweahter 34134    FM34
```

The first `sub` extract 1st character out of two words in `name` column and the second `sub` extract last two characters from `zip` column. We combine them together in one column using `paste0`.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("Mike Tyson", "Mohammed Ali", "Joe Frazier", 
"Floyd Mayweahter"), zip = c(13756L, 54412L, 47463L, 34134L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new.var = paste(str_extract(name, "^."),
                         str_extract(sub(".* ","", name),"^."),
                         str_extract(zip,"..$"),
                         sep = ""))
```

Output:

```
              name   zip new.var
1       Mike Tyson 13756    MT56
2     Mohammed Ali 54412    MA12
3      Joe Frazier 47463    JF63
4 Floyd Mayweahter 34134    FM34
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base` R

```
df %>% mutate(mm =  gsub('\\b(\\pL)\\pL{2,}|.','\\U\\1', name, perl = TRUE))%>% 
      mutate(vv = substring(zip, 4,6)) %>% 
     mutate(var = paste0(mm,vv)) %>% 
  select('name', 'zip', 'var')

              name   zip  var
1       Mike Tyson 13756 MT56
2     Mohammed Ali 54412 MA12
3      Joe Frazier 47463 JF63
4 Floyd Mayweahter 34134 FM34
```

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(new.var = str_c(str_remove_all(name, "[a-z ]+"), substr(zip, 4,5)))
              name   zip new.var
1       Mike Tyson 13756    MT56
2     Mohammed Ali 54412    MA12
3      Joe Frazier 47463    JF63
4 Floyd Mayweahter 34134    FM34
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("Mike Tyson", "Mohammed Ali", "Joe Frazier", 
"Floyd Mayweahter"), zip = c(13756L, 54412L, 47463L, 34134L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```